# How do you store and retrieve a StringDictionary in app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config, stringdictionary

I have a list of information in a string dictionary that I want to store in the app.config for my program.

I've created the entry in the "settings" portion of the program called "extentions" but when I go to use "Settings.Default.Extentions" I get an error that it is null.

Is there a trick or something to using this?

```
private void LoadextList()
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Settings.Default.Extentions)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Key + "\t" + kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code / screenshot where you created Extensions?

Comment: I created extentions in the propertys of the project under settings as a collections.special.stringdictonary ( i can post a screen gab if you really really want it)

Comment: I should also mention that i can do this with a string in app.config. Im just confused how to do it with a string dictionary.

Comment: See this elegant solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338242/how-do-i-store-a-dictionary-object-in-my-web-config-file

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your Extensions problem, but I've used this code before to convert between a string and NameValueCollection - you can easily change it to use a StringDictionary:

```
    public NameValueCollection StringToNameValueCollection(string KeyValueData, char KeyValueSeparator, char ItemSeparator)
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

        // split string into array of key/value pairs
        string[] kvpairs = KeyValueData.Split(new char[]{ItemSeparator});

        // add each pair to the collection
        for (int i = 0; i < kvpairs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvpairs[i]))
            {
                if (kvpairs[i].Contains(KeyValueSeparator.ToString()))
                {
                    // get the key
                    string k = kvpairs[i].Remove(kvpairs[i].IndexOf(KeyValueSeparator.ToString())).Trim();
                    // get the value
                    string v = kvpairs[i].Remove(0, kvpairs[i].IndexOf(KeyValueSeparator) + 1).Trim();

                    // add key/value if key is valid
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(k))
                    {
                        nvc.Add(k, v);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // no key/value separator in the pair, so add whole string as key and value
                    nvc.Add(kvpairs[i].Trim(), kvpairs[i].Trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return nvc;
    }
```

Convert NameValueCollection to string:

```
    public string NameValueCollectionToString(NameValueCollection nvc, char KeyValueSeparator, char ItemSeparator)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                sb.Append(ItemSeparator);
            }
            sb.Append(nvc.Keys[i]);
            sb.Append(KeyValueSeparator);
            sb.Append(nvc[i]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I've had to make a couple of changes from the code I used, but it should build. Note that it's not too forgiving - the separator characters cannot appear in either the 'key' or 'value' strings.

Comment: that would probably get me around the issue. ill give it a try, I still feel like i'm missing soemthing fundimental about not knowing why i cant save that stringdictonary.

Comment: Im sorting it out now but your first method throws an error that not all paths give a return

(i can probably figure it out but you might wnat to edit your code for the masses)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a missed a brace out, should be ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The following question probably contains useful information:

[How to store a HashTable in the usersettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775246/how-to-store-a-hashtable-in-the-usersettings/1776923#1776923)

The problem you are facing is that the two serialization options available when you use a Settings.settings file and the associated auto-generated class are serialization to XML or serialization to string.

The `StringDictionary` class does not support neither XML nor string serialization. There are some ways you can workaround this limitation and a few of them are listed on the answers to previously mentioned question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public Dictionary<string,string> StringToDictonary(string KeyValueData, char KeyValueSeparator, char ItemSeparator)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string[] cells = KeyValueData.Split(ItemSeparator);
    foreach (string cell in cells)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell))
        {
            string[] value = cell.Split(KeyValueSeparator);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value[0]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value[1]))
            {
                Dic.Add(value[0], value[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return Dic;
}
```

break

```
    public string dictonaryToString(Dictionary<string, string> nvc, char KeyValueSeparator, char ItemSeparator)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool first = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in nvc)
        {
            if (!first)
            {
                sb.Append(ItemSeparator);
                first = false;
            }
            sb.Append(kvp.Key);
            sb.Append(KeyValueSeparator);
            sb.Append(kvp.Value);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```