# c# Save Multidim ArrayList to Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, settings

Is it possible to save a multidimensional ArrayList to the Properties.Settings? I get errors when i try to.

If not, is there any other way i can save some sort of multidimensional thingie to the Properties.Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I remember fighting with `Properties.Settings`... never a fun battle :(. The quick and dirty option would be to use different separator characters to do a string "serialization" (in quotes because a real serialization would be much better about handling edge cases etc.). Something like this:

```
int[][] myArray = GetArrayFromElsewhere();
string stringVersion = string.Join(";", myArray.Select(subArray => string.Join(",", subArray)));
Properties.Settings.StringVersion = stringVersion;
```

You could also use esoteric Unicode characters instead of `;` and `,`, so as to avoid accidentally splitting a string, and you could use a loop (or probably recursion) to generalize this to any number of dimensions.

But, this is of course a quick and dirty workaround. The real solution would be to do some sort of [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx) of the multidimensional array. You might be able to get away with just some simple `XmlSerializer` or `BinaryFormatter` or even `JavaScriptSerializer` code---actually, I think the last of those might work really well---but if you need to get more complicated, [this question discusses a similar solution for a hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775246/how-to-store-a-hashtable-in-the-usersettings), with lots of gory details.