# Error using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get() in ASP MVC3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use the `Authorize` class in my ASP MVC3 app. Unfortunately due to business rules I need to pull the `Roles` from our web.config, however this is throwing the following exception:

```
An attribute must be a constant expression, typeof or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

Here is the code I'm referencing.

```
[Authorize(Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("user"))]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
```

Here is the `user` section of my web.config

```
<add key="user" value="SA\\Application.MortalityConcentrationRA.Dev.Users" />
```

Comment: Can you show the appsetting section of your web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a custom authorize attribute like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public MyAuthorizeAttribute()
        {
            this.Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"];
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
}
```

And using it in your controller like this:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need a custom authorize attribute. I looked around a bit and didn't find any other possible solution. The current attribute is requiring a constant, and I just do not know of a way to have your config.AppSettings[] ever be a constant value (it's pretty much by definition not a constant).

Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539217/specifying-roles-in-web-config-of-an-asp-net-mvc-application) that explains pretty much exactly what you need to do. You question is almost a duplicate of this one (which is good for you, there's already an answer).