# Set AD Roles name on web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I'm using `Windows authentication` to allow some users to access my controllers. This is my `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="WindowsProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="WindowsProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
</system.web>
```

And this is my `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"MyDomain\MyUploadRole")]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

I want to add the string `@"MyDomain\MyUploadRole"` to the `web.config` but I don't know how to do it.

I have tested this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540409/68571), but it doesn't work for me. I have added this part to `web.config` file:

```
<roles>
  <add key="Role1" value="MyDomain\MyUploadRole" />
  <add key="Role2" value="MyDomain\Another role" />
</roles>
```

And then, I change this on controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Role1")]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

And Internet Explorer ask for my credentials, but I get unauthorized response.

How can I set role's name on `web.config`?

Comment: whats with something like that: <allow users="domain\user" roles="domain\group"  />

Comment: @DasDas Some controllers needs a role and some of them don't.

Comment: Why didn't that other answer work for you?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Can you show us the inner workings of the custom authorize code, or is it exactly the same as the SO answer you've linked to?

Comment: It is not a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you:

```
<configuration>    
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
     <allow roles="MyDomain\MyUploadRole"/>
     <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>
```

And in your code you can check to see whether the user is in a role like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyDomain\MyUploadRole")
```